# Simple test route is not responding to simple Postman request

Tags: express, routes, postman

I tried to create the simplest test route to test on my localhost as follows.

Verified localhost:3000 is up.  Wrote a simple test file.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/test').get((req, res) => {
  console.log('route found');
});

module.exports = router;
```

My routes are split up as follows in my index routing file in the routes directory.

```
module.exports.api = require('./api');
module.exports.auth = require('./auth');
module.exports.root = require('./root');
module.exports.articles = require('./articles');
module.exports.test = require('./test');
```

I use the route as follows in my index.js for the server:

```
const routes = require(__dirname + '/routes');
app.use('/test', routes.test);
```

Tested it using Postman.

Sent request to `localhost:3000/test/test`.

No response.  How can I troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any response because you are not sending any response from the server. You need to send some response back otherwise the client will keep waiting for the response until request times out.

```
router.route('/test').get((req, res) => {
  res.send('route not found');
});
```

#### Edit

`app.use('/test', routes.test);` won't work with the way your route is defined. For it to work, request url should be `/test/test`. If you want request url to be just `/test`, change

```
app.use('/test', routes.test);
```

to

```
app.use(routes.test);
```

Comment: But I should still see the console.log in my localhost or not?

Comment: Thanks, but still Postman just hangs there even after adding a res.send command.

Comment: @j.a yes you should see a console.log on your console. Make sure your server is running

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version of what you want to do

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hey");
    console.log('route found');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now in your main module, you need to check that you're listening to the right port, and that your express app is actually using the exported router!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require('path/to/router/module');

app.use(router)
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("listening to port 8080"));
```

### EDIT:

You mentioned that

> My routes are split up as follows in my index routing file in the routes directory.

And, I can see that in the main module, you are requiring the directory itself, and not the routes module

```
const routes = require(__dirname + '/routes');
```

while what you should require is a module and not a directory!

```
const routes = require(__dirname + '/routes/yourRouteModuleName');
```

The solution I just gave assumes the following project's structure:

```
├── index.js
├── routes
│   ├── test.js
│   ├── routeModuleOrWhatever.js
│
```

Comment: Verified that localhost is running and that the route was set.  I updated my question to show the `app.use` command.

Comment: I am using port 3000 by the way for localhost.

Comment: My syntax is a bit different.  However I did change my sub route to test1 so there is no confusion between super and sub route.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know what code to post, so I did not post enough code.  I updated my Q to have all the code but I have a folder called routes that has a file for each set of routes.  An index file then consolidates these route files so I can just use one require command to access them.  All the relevant code should be posted now.